# Выводится "NaN" при попытке по нажатию кнопки добавить единицу к javascript переменной

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная, к которой должна добавиться единица при нажатии на кнопку, значение отображается в input. Но при нажатии вместо добавления единицы выводится `NaN`. В чем ошибка? UPD: Спасибо за ответы.

```js
var f = 1;
document.getElementById('out').value = f;
function change() {
 if (f == 10) {
  var f = 1;
 }
 else {
  f++;
  document.getElementById('out').value = f;
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="change()" value="qq">
<input id='out'>
```

Comment: `undefined + 1`

Comment: `var f = 1;` внутри функции `var` уберите

Comment: Прочитать в учебнике главу про область видимости переменных

Comment: `var f = 1`  уберите `var`, у вас переменная уже определена в глобальной области